# OpenCV - Visual Studio 2015 find contours error

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I'm having trouble with openCV 3.1 on Visual Studio 2015. I've been getting run time errors whenever I call the function find contours. I've tried looking into this and I've mostly found people stating that linking the release library o the debug configuration causes this, but I've ensured that I'm not making said mistake (linking opencv_310d.lib).

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void*);

/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /// Load source image and convert it to gray
    src = imread("security.png", 1);

    /// Convert image to gray and blur it
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3, 3));

    /// Create Window
    char* source_window = "Source";
    namedWindow(source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow(source_window, src);

    createTrackbar(" Canny thresh:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback);
    thresh_callback(0, 0);

    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}

/** @function thresh_callback */
void thresh_callback(int, void*)
{
    Mat canny_output;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    /// Detect edges using canny
    Canny(src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh * 2, 3);
    /// Find contours
    findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    
}
```

It seems to run fine if I comment out the call to findContours(). It might be a .dll issue but I'm not entirely certain on how to figure it out.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPOIe.png)

My project properties:
Configuration: Active (debug)     Platform: Acttive (x64)

C/C++=> General=> Additional Include Directories: C:\opencv\build\include

Linker=> General=> Additional Library Directories: C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib

Linker=> Input=> Additional Dependencies: opencv_world310d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Configuration: Release

C/C++=> General=> Additional Include Directories:%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

Linker=> General=> Additional Library Directories:%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

Linker=> Input=> Additional Dependencies: opencv_world310.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Comment: Yep... you're linking something wrong... please show your additional library dirs, and linked libs in both debug and release

Comment: @Miki I've added my project's properties for the debug and release configuration to the post. I can't really identify what's wrong.

Comment: I am facing the same problem on openCV 3.2 on Visual Studio 2015. I used the following you tube for setting up the environment, it shows the linking as well, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrIpAztWv1Q